# Qual a diferença entre Class e id em CSS?

Tags: css, classes, formatação, id, style

Estou iniciando em CSS e vi essas duas propriedades que são parecidas e exercem a mesma função,então de algum modo elas devem ter alguma diferença ou outro tipo de função talvez,queria saber a diferença entre elas (Class e id) ou (. e #)

Answer (score 3):

Boa noite, de maneira simples uma classe é uma maneira de identificar um grupo de elementos como pro exemplo class="button" já o Id é um identificador único para um elemento.

Os elementos no HTML podem conter varias classes exemplo `class="button btn-success"` mas somente um único Id `id="myButton"`.

Comment: me salvou cara,vlw !